# Localizing Title in Windows Phone Not Changing Title?

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization, windows-phone, title, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a Win32 project for it according to [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx#WP_CreateaLanguageResourceDLL) and imported Italiona, Turkish and neutral DLL's to my WP application. Neutral is running correctly but when I chnage my emulator's or phone's language, title and tile title don't change.

[image: Solution]

What can be it's reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1 Win-RT you do not need a dll.

Here's a set of screenshots as a step by step guide:

http://s27.postimg.org/nz4xweo7n/Localize_App_Name.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've add the control you wanted to change(In your case the Title) through the `AppResources.resx` of the respective language.

[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/localization-support-in-windows-phone-8-apps/) should help you. Refer this one too.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manish1231/windows-phone-8-app-localization/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for interest but Title Localizing isn't like in localizing app strings. It is doing with C++ DLL.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [post](http://wpdevkvk.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/localizing-your-windows-phone-app/), It explains in detail how to localize your app quickly and easily.

- You need to add Key Value pairs to the `AppResource.resx` file in the Resources folder. The values should be the Strings you need to translate to other languages and the key is used to call them in XAML or in code.
- Install Multilingual App Toolkit and enable it in VS.
- After you added the strings to the `AppResources.resx` file, you can use Multilingual App Toolkit to generate the other `AppResources` files for each of the languages you need to translate.
- Then you can use Multilingual App Toolkit editor to either translate them automatically using Bing Translate or you can do it manually.

Comment: @KasunKV, thank you for interest but Title Localizing isn't like in localizing app strings.